# Unable to Create a new account from Scaffolding

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core, scaffolding

I'm trying to create authorization and authentication from scratch using the new Identity scaffolding in the new .Net Core 2.1 but keep getting this error.

**SqlException: Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'.**

RegisterModel fails to execute on this line:

```
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
```

IDENTITYHOSTINGSTARTUP.CS

```
[assembly: HostingStartup(typeof(Authorize.Areas.Identity.IdentityHostingStartup))]
namespace Authorize.Areas.Identity
{
    public class IdentityHostingStartup : IHostingStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
                services.AddDbContext<AuthorizeContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(
                        context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AuthorizeContextConnection")));

                services.AddDefaultIdentity<AuthorizeUser>()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthorizeContext>()
                    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error usual suggests that you do not have the AspNetUsers table in your database. Have you ran the migrations provided in the scaffold? This can be done through either a powershell or console terminal. Navigate to the web project and execute `Update-Database` if using powershell or `dotnet ef database update` for  console.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/

Comment: Error has been fixed. Thanks, anyways. And yes...I forgot to run the migration and update-database. See, in previous versions, you didn't need to do all that. Still getting used to this new version 2.1